# Chromium profile directory is already used/locked by another browser

Tags: dotnetbrowser

I am using dotnetbrowser-1.11 in two different applications. If any one of this application is already running, then the other application throws the following error on creating browser instance.

Chromium profile directory is already used/locked by another browser.

Would like to mention that this issue is specific to  dotnetbrowser-1.11, since i had no problem in running multiple applications with dotnetbrowser-1.10[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a check that was added in DotNetBrowser 1.11. This was done to prevent different BrowserContext instances from using the same data directory because such configuration can cause unpredictable behavior and random crashes in the Chromium engine.

The following article contains a warning related to such use-cases:
https://dotnetbrowser.support.teamdev.com/solution/articles/9000109311-creating-browser

> Make sure that you don't use several BrowserContext instances configured to use same data directory.  In this case Chromium engine will read/write same data directory from different Browser instances which might cause unexpected behavior or errors including crash in Chromium engine.

Comment: Thanks i was able to solve the above by setting different data directory to the browser context.