# Create WPF BrowserView defined in XAML with custom BrowserContext

Tags: wpf, xaml, dotnetbrowser

I've got a DotNetBrowser instance defined in a XAML file

```
<Grid>
  <wpf:WPFBrowserView x:Name="BrowserView"></wpf:WPFBrowserView>
</Grid>
```

The application is used by multiple people, which is causing issues due to the issue discussed here:

[Chromium profile directory is already used/locked by another browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45236391/chromium-profile-directory-is-already-used-locked-by-another-browser)

Is it possible to use XAML to define the browser control and still assign a custom context to the browser instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to use XAML to define the browser control and still assign a custom context to the browser instance?

No, I am afraid it's not.

The `Browser` property of the `WPFBrowserView` class doesn't have a public setter so you must create the custom `Browser` and the `BrowserContext` programmatically:

```
BrowserContextParams params1 = new BrowserContextParams("C:\\my-data1");
BrowserContext context1 = new BrowserContext(params1);
Browser browser1 = BrowserFactory.Create(context1);
```

XAML doesn't support anything like calling `BrowserFactory.Create(context1)`.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the custom `BrowserContext` can be configured only if the `Browser` and `WPFBrowserView` were created from the source code.

The possible approach is to wrap `WPFBrowserView` and its non-default initialization into a custom control that manages instantiating and disposal of the `WPFBrowserView`, make this control expose all the necessary properties and then insert it into your XAML.